# How to print 1 sheet which was changed by VLOOKUP in 1 PDF files

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my old code. This code will print many files depends on how many it has been looped. I want to modify it to **PrintOut** in 1 file (multiple pages). Is it possible to do?

FYI
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 16).Value is the dynamic value which can be 1 to n to VLOOKUP the data from another sheet. If I set Cells(1,16) to 4, it will print 4 files from the same sheet but different data.

```
Sub PrintAll()

    Dim i, s, e As Integer
    
    s = 1
    e = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 16).Value
    For i = s To e
        ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 4).Value = i
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
    Next i
    
    ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 4).Value = 1
    
End Sub
```

I tried to store ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets in Object array but it can't be printed. I even tried to store it in Worksheet array as well then I faced the same problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
Sub PrintAll()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim s As Integer
    Dim e As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    s = 1
    e = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 16).Value

    Dim wsNames() As String
    ReDim wsNames(1 To e)

    For i = s To e
        Set ws = Sheets("DataSht")
        ws.Cells(7, 4).Value = i
        ws.Copy Before:=Sheets("QuoteSheet")
        wsNames(i) = "DataSht (" & i + 1 & ")"
    Next i

    ' Print all sheets
    Sheets(wsNames).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Users\User\Downloads\File.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets(wsNames).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Sheets("DataSht").Cells(7, 4).Value = 1
End Sub
```

I use 2019 Excel. My concept is create tabs that I want to print -> print -> delete that tabs. I can't print multiple pages in 1 tab(vlookup 3++ times) so I try that concept.